# manga identification help

Tags: classmate-kamimura-yuuka

Last year I read a manga of which I remember quite some bits. It was an interesting one but I don't remember it's name or characters name please help me find it.. here's what i remember-

- the main character is a teen boy in class probably high school
  thinking about his life and his best friend/classmate greets him
  everyday.
- the main character develops self awareness & realizes a repetition in
  everyone's life or everyone is maybe programmed. when he tries to question his classmates they get hostile towards him but maybe go normal after sometime like nothing happened. and his best friend too gains self awareness they realize they can't recall their past or when they spent time together etc.
- their group gets a bit bigger and they find out there is a wall
  around the city they even get attacked by a robot which main
  character defeats..
- I also recall scenes like them making a hole in the wall to pass
  through and main character telling others that they never went out to
  buy food or anything but still find their necessary items everyday so
  something must be in charge of them.
- also when they get out they walk a lot and find another city.

  hope this much info is enough.. thank you in advance please if you know the name of this manga do tell.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manga your looking for is [Classmate, Kamimura Yuuka wa Kou Itta](http://myanimelist.net/manga/28537/Classmate_Kamimura_Yuuka_wa_Kou_Itta)

[image]

> Shirasaki is incredibly bored by his unchanging daily school life and he ends up falling in with his weird classmate Kamimura Yuuka, who rants about changing the world to his uninterested classmates. However, when she reveals the truth about the nature of their world to him, everything will quickly become stranger than he would ever have expected!

Comment: thnx a lot swswsws.. :) and sorry for the inconvenience  guys I just used it for first time that too on a mob. hope you understand.. anyways thanks again y'all :)

Comment: No problem and your welcome.